# Is there a way to enforce layout constraints between components in different panels?

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager

This is a java SWING question. I have strict specifications on how components in my UI must be aligned. I can achieve this by using GridBagLayout and putting all my components in the same panel. However, this approach is going to make the code difficult to maintain. Ideally I'd like to be able to put logically distinct components in separate panels and specify some alignment constraints. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: No, not really, however, I've heard good things about MigLayout when it comes to trying to do these type of things

Comment: If you can do it with a single panel using a GridBagLayout then you should be able to do it with multiple logical panels each using a GridBagLayout. Keeping the components smaller may make it easer to maintain. Without a concrete example I'm not sure if this approach will work or not since I don't know the constraints you are talking about.